# Switching from networking to netplan

Tags: networking, network-interface, netplan

I am switching from Ubuntu to Debian, but - as I can only access the VM via ssh - I very much miss the `netplan try` feature. Whenever I mess up the `/etc/network/interfaces`, I am out and need help from the hoster.

Installing `netplan` on Debian Buster is simple enough (`apt install netplan.io`), but whatever I then do to the `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file, it seems to have no effect. When I try the new configuration (via `netplan try`) it says that the new configuration would be in effect, but `ip address` says that it is not.

So my question is: How do I actually switch control over the network interfaces over from `networking` to `netplan`?

Answer (score 1):

Netplan can render configuration for `NetworkManager` or `systemd-networkd` backend.
You have to select it in your yaml file as in the example below:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```

When you run `netplan generate` it will create configuration file under `/run/systemd/network/`

Debian by default is using `networking` service.
What you need to do is to switch from `networking` to `systemd-networkd`

```
systemctl enable --now systemd-networkd && systemctl disable --now networking
```

Mask the networking so it won't be started accidently

```
systemctl mask networking
```

Alternatively to masking you can uninstall `ifupdown`

```
apt purge ifupdown
```

Answer (score -1):

I am no expert so correct me if i am wrong. This is what i did to get netplan to work on my debian machine.

Most likely your config file is incorrect or has a wrong filename.
For example `/etc/netplan/ens192.yaml` (filename could be anything). The extension (yaml) is the important part.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      dhcp4: true
```

To be complete here are the commands to install netplan:

```
apt update
apt install netplan.io -y
```

Backup the interfaces file

```
mv /etc/network/interfaces ~/interfaces
```

Comment: OP is indicating that he has netplan installed and that he tries it and it does not work, therefore your answer adds no value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).